# Detect specific changes in text field with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to detect only new text input to a text field. The following code works but returns the entire text field, not just the text that is typed, pasted, etc.

Example A: If the text field contains "1245" and the user types "3", the current code alerts "12345" but I'd like it to only alert "3".

Example B: If the text field contains "12345" and the user pastes "67890", the current code alerts "1234567890" but I'd like it to only alert "67890".

```
    <input id="input" name="input"
        onchange 
        onpropertychange 
        onkeyuponpaste oninput="inputReturn(this)"> 

    <script> 
    function inputReturn(changeVal) {
        alert(changeVal.value);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works. Using html features, you will always get alerted with the current value of the field, not the modifications to it.

If you really need to be alerted of what the user types, you can listen to keyboard events and try to make something out of it.

Or you can keep track of the previous value of the field and compare it to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this:

```
  <input id="input" name="input"
        onchange 
        onpropertychange 
        prevalue=""
        onkeyuponpaste oninput="inputReturn(this)"> 

    <script> 
       function inputReturn(changeVal) {
        if (changeVal.prevalue) {
          alert(changeVal.value.substr(changeVal.prevalue.length));
        } else {
           alert(changeVal.value);
        }
        changeVal.prevalue = changeVal.value;
      }
    </script>
```